# No cargan los eventos de los elementos html luego llamarlos desde una base de datos

Tags: api, script, fetch

tratare de ser muy especifico.
tengo un problema y lo tengo hace tiempo, nuevamente se me presenta y no se que hacer.
Contexto:
Resulta que cuando realizo una peticion a un api o a alguna ruta que me devuelva datos al momento de pintarlos las funciones de script o estilos de este  elemento (dentro del diseño html o plantilla) se pierden y dejan de funcionar, a que me refiero:
digamos que tenemos un SLIDER, el cual muestra imagenes con cierto estilo y propiedades unicas de el, ejemplo: http://cssslider.com/es/bootstrap-slider-10.html

si yo quiero llenar ese slider con imagenes dinamicas usando javascrip (hago una peticion a una base de dato que me devuelve las url) - (ajax o fetch) luego de hacer esta peticion y obtener los datos las propiedades de ese slider se pierden por completo. (este es mi gran problema)

significa que ya no puedo ver todas las imagenes haciendo tocuh en el slider, solo se muestra una, y aunque en el codigo html se vean (usando el inspector), no funciona el slider.

```js
    async function getJSON() {

      let tab =``;
    return fetch("api_con_url")
        .then((response)=>response.json())
        .then((responseJson)=>{/* responseJson*/
        
          let tab3 = ``; 
   for (let x  of responseJson){
  

   tab3 += ` <div class="swiper-slide">SLIDE ${x.numero} </div>`; 
   }
   document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML =''+ tab3; 
        });
}
getJSON();


    var swiper = new Swiper('.mySwiper', {
      pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
      slidesPerView: 1,
      paginationClickable: true,
      spaceBetween: 30,
      // Navigation arrows
  nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
  prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
  });
```

```css
 <!-- Demo styles -->

      html,
      body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;

        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
```

```html
  <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"
    />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    
      <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
      
    <!-- Swiper -->
    
   <!-- AQUI DEBERIA MOSTRARLAS PERO NO FUNCIONA -->
   <h1>NO FUNCIONA</h1>
  <div id="lista" style="height: 50%;">
    
  </div>
  
  
  <!-- SE DEBERIA VER ASI -->
  
  <h1>COMO SE DEBERIA VER</h1>
  
    <div style="height: 90%;"  class="swiper mySwiper">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    </div>
```

Esto me pasa usando ya sea fetch y ajax, no se como solucionarlo, (ya ven que el problema es basicamente que se pierden las propiedades de ejecucion de los eventos de ese elemento)
si tienen alguna idea o solucion les agradeceria

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function getJSON() {
    /**@todo Cargas los datos del API*/
    let responseJson = [1,2,3];
    let tab3="";
    for (let x  of responseJson){
     tab3 += ` <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="http://cssslider.com/sliders/demo-10/data1/images/${x}.jpg" alt="Responsive  carousel " title="Material Design">  </div>`; 
    }
    document.getElementById("lista").innerHTML =''+ tab3;         


}
async function initSlider (){
    await getJSON();
    var swiper = new Swiper('.mySwiper', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        slidesPerView: 1,
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
            // Navigation arrows
        nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    });
}

initSlider()
```

```css
html,
      body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;

        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div style="height: 90%;"  class="swiper mySwiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper" id="lista">

  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

El problema radica en que **getJSON();** es una **Promesa**, por lo que no espera a que termine la carga para inicializar el **swiper**, una vez inicializado el **swiper** se romperá si cargas nuevos datos ya que está pensado para **renderizar y trabajar estático**. una solución es esperar que termine **await getJSON()** y luego ejecutar la creación del **swiper**, crea métodos diferentes y llama a cada en orden, en la  [documentación](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-preloadImages)  te explica el método: **preloadImages**, que fuerza la carga de las imágenes. puedes utilizar esta como segunda solución combinando con un reload del js, *para que se construya **swiper** en el momento que termine la carga del JSON*

Comment: vale ya veo, me puedes indicar un script donde primero se cargue todo para que luego se pinte evitando el problema de las cargas, te agradeceria bastante

Comment: Tienes un ejemplo en mi respuesta, solo tienes que adaptarlo